# Why gradle plugin 3.3.0 doesn't want to build google-services?

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, google-play-services, android-gradle-plugin-3.3.0

I'm trying to **Sync** my project with `gradle:3.3.0` , but in result file `values.xml` for google-services is not generated in folder: `D:\Android\workspace\myproject\app\build\generated\res\google-services\debug\values\values.xml`

Top level build file **build.gradle**:

```
 apply plugin: 'kotlin'

    buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.11'
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
          }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            mavenLocal()
            google()
            jcenter()
            mavenCentral()
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        }

        configurations.all {
            exclude group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', module: 'kotlin-stdlib-jre7'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    }

    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "1.8"
        }
    }
    compileTestKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "1.8"
        }
    }
```

**app/build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    ...
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0"
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**google-services.json**

File `google-services.json` is located in `D:\Android\workspace\myproject\app\google-services.json`

In result after run of app the error occurs:

```
 01-23 10:31:31.578 30044-30073/E/FA: GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing google app id value from from string resources with name google_app_id.
01-23 10:31:31.578 30044-30073/E/FA: Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled. See 
01-23 10:31:33.758 30044-30044/ E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: , PID: 30044
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process . Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.4:240)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't update to com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54441456/cant-update-to-com-google-gmsgoogle-services4-2-0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove dependencies block from top-level gradle file:

```
dependencies {
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    }
```

And update to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'` and `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'`
In result your Gradle Files should be Like This For Android Studio 3.3 (stable channel)

**build.gradle(project:yourProject)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.11'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

        // Add repository
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1'



        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

        // Add repository
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

---

**build.gradle(Module:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}



android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "sanaebadi.info.teacherhandler"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'

    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    def room_version = "2.1.0-alpha03"
    def lifecycle_version = "2.0.0"


    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'

    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'



    //Firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.8'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
}
```

---

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
#Tue Jan 15 07:24:23 EST 2019
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
```

Comment: the error occurs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54441456/cant-update-to-com-google-gmsgoogle-services4-2-0

Answer (score 1):

update to `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'` in project level build.gradle.

Comment: After sync `> Configure project :app
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

CONFIGURE SUCCESSFUL in 16s

1`

Comment: As you see at the end there is error `1`. What it means?