# Can't update to com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, gradle, google-play-services

At start google-services ver. is `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'`, but when I change it to `4.2.0` the error occurs during `Sync Project with Gradle files`

My top level gradle:

```
 // Top-level build file

apply plugin: 'kotlin'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.20'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

        maven { url 'http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local' }

    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.orhanobut.tracklytics:tracklytics-plugin:2.0.0'

        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'

        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.8.0"

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }

    configurations.all {
        exclude group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', module: 'kotlin-stdlib-jre7'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

My app/build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
   ...

    defaultConfig {
     ...
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }


    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "8g"
        preDexLibraries = false
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }

}

dependencies {
  ...

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

[image]
Here is full stack of error from `c:\Users\User\.AndroidStudio3.3\system\log\`

```
2019-01-30 15:54:39,983 [entQueue-0]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Consuming IndexingSuspender activation event: SYNC_TASK_CREATED 
2019-01-30 15:54:39,983 [entQueue-0]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Started sync with Gradle for project 'MyProject'. 
2019-01-30 15:54:39,984 [entQueue-0]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Consuming IndexingSuspender activation event: SYNC_STARTED 
2019-01-30 15:54:39,984 [entQueue-0]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Starting batch update for project: Project 'D:\Android\workspace\MyProject' MyProject 
2019-01-30 15:54:39,994 [ thread 38]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_201 
2019-01-30 15:54:39,995 [ thread 38]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_201 
2019-01-30 15:54:40,000 [ thread 38]   INFO - xecution.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line args to Gradle Tooling API: -Didea.version=3.3 -Djava.awt.headless=true -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only=true -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only.advanced=true -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only.versioned=3 -Pandroid.injected.studio.version=3.3.0.20 --init-script C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ijinit.gradle 
2019-01-30 15:54:41,606 [ thread 38]   INFO - .project.GradleProjectResolver - Gradle project resolve error 
org.gradle.tooling.BuildActionFailureException: The supplied build action failed with an exception.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableActionRunner.run(CancellableActionRunner.java:56)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.AbstractConsumerConnection.run(AbstractConsumerConnection.java:63)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ParameterValidatingConsumerConnection.run(ParameterValidatingConsumerConnection.java:54)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter$1.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:76)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:84)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.run(CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.run(RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:65)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:274)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.access$100(GradleProjectResolver.java:76)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:879)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:863)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:209)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:141)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:76)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.lambda$resolveProjectInfo$0(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:58)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:45)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:100)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:163)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:149)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:573)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$5.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:678)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:736)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:580)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:525)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:85)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:144)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$4.run(CoreProgressManager.java:395)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at com.google.android.gms.dependencies.DependencyInspector.registerDependencies(DependencyInspector.java:118)
    at com.google.android.gms.dependencies.DependencyInspector.afterResolve(DependencyInspector.java:173)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor90.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$ListenerDetails.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:370)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$ListenerDetails.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:352)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$EventBroadcast$ListenerDispatch.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:340)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$EventBroadcast$ListenerDispatch.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:327)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:230)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:149)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:140)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24.afterResolve(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$4.run(DefaultConfiguration.java:502)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveGraphIfRequired(DefaultConfiguration.java:485)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveToStateOrLater(DefaultConfiguration.java:470)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$1700(DefaultConfiguration.java:120)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getSelectedArtifacts(DefaultConfiguration.java:927)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.access$2700(DefaultConfiguration.java:861)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationArtifactCollection.ensureResolved(DefaultConfiguration.java:1279)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationArtifactCollection.iterator(DefaultConfiguration.java:1263)
    at org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.resolver.IdeDependencySet$IdeDependencyResult.resolvePlusConfigurations(IdeDependencySet.java:98)
    at org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.resolver.IdeDependencySet$IdeDependencyResult.visit(IdeDependencySet.java:88)
    at org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.resolver.IdeDependencySet.visit(IdeDependencySet.java:71)
    at org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.internal.IdeaDependenciesProvider.visitDependencies(IdeaDependenciesProvider.java:103)
    at org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.internal.IdeaDependenciesProvider.getDependencies(IdeaDependenciesProvider.java:88)
    at org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.internal.IdeaDependenciesProvider.provide(IdeaDependenciesProvider.java:64)
    at org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModule.resolveDependencies(IdeaModule.java:533)
    at org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.tooling.IdeaModelBuilder.buildDependencies(IdeaModelBuilder.java:125)
    at org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.tooling.IdeaModelBuilder.build(IdeaModelBuilder.java:112)
    at org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.tooling.IdeaModelBuilder.buildAll(IdeaModelBuilder.java:78)
    at org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.tooling.IdeaModelBuilder.buildAll(IdeaModelBuilder.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.DefaultBuildController.getModel(DefaultBuildController.java:79)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.InternalBuildActionAdapter$2.getModel(InternalBuildActionAdapter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.BuildControllerAdapter.getModel(BuildControllerAdapter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.AbstractBuildController.getModel(AbstractBuildController.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.AbstractBuildController.getModel(AbstractBuildController.java:28)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:68)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.InternalBuildActionAdapter.execute(InternalBuildActionAdapter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.buildResult(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:77)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.access$000(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:37)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$1.buildFinished(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor237.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$ListenerDetails.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:370)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$ListenerDetails.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:352)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$EventBroadcast$ListenerDispatch.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:340)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$EventBroadcast$ListenerDispatch.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:327)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:230)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:149)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:324)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:234)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:140)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17.buildFinished(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.finishBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:154)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.finishBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:122)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$2.call(GradleBuildController.java:88)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$2.call(GradleBuildController.java:84)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:100)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.configure(GradleBuildController.java:84)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:64)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-01-30 15:54:41,609 [ thread 38]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - 1 
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: 1
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.ProjectImportErrorHandler.getUserFriendlyError(ProjectImportErrorHandler.java:72)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.getUserFriendlyError(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:468)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:150)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.JavaGradleProjectResolver.getUserFriendlyError(JavaGradleProjectResolver.java:94)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:150)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:150)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:883)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:863)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:209)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:141)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:76)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.lambda$resolveProjectInfo$0(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:58)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:45)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:100)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:163)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:149)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:573)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$5.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:678)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:736)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:580)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:525)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:85)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:144)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$4.run(CoreProgressManager.java:395)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


2019-01-30 15:54:41,609 [ thread 38]   INFO - System.util.ExternalSystemUtil - External project [D:/Android/workspace/MyProject] resolution task executed in 1619 ms. 
2019-01-30 15:54:41,609 [ thread 38]   WARN - ect.sync.idea.ProjectSetUpTask - 1 
2019-01-30 15:54:41,610 [ thread 38]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Gradle sync failed: 1

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (1 s 626 ms) 
2019-01-30 15:54:41,611 [entQueue-0]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Consuming IndexingSuspender deactivation event: SYNC_FINISHED 
2019-01-30 15:54:41,611 [entQueue-0]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Finishing batch update for project: Project 'D:\Android\workspace\MyProject' MyProject 
2019-01-30 15:54:41,681 [ thread 38]   INFO - roid.tools.ndk.GradleWorkspace - Updating model took 0.0s
```

Comment: Please add the code that produces that `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` and indicate the exact line at which it occurs.

Comment: @AlexMamo At start google-services ver. is `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'`, but when I change it to `4.2.0` the error occurs during `Sync Project with Gradle files`

Comment: have you enabled jetifier?

Comment: @KaranMer I tried to add in `gradle.properties` file: `android.useAndroidX=true` and `android.enableJetifier=true` and it didn't help me

Comment: did you add `google-services.json` to the project?

Comment: @KaranMer yes, in top of question there is link to my project

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@NickUnuchek leave the dependencies block out of the gradle file of your root project, then it will work

In result top level gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

apply plugin: 'kotlin'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.20'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        //region realm
        maven { url 'http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local' }
        //endregion
    }
    dependencies {
        //region google()
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        //endregion
        //region jcenter()
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.orhanobut.tracklytics:tracklytics-plugin:2.0.0'
        //endregion
        //region maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        //to check fabric gradle ver
        //https://s3.amazonaws.com/fabric-artifacts/public/io/fabric/tools/gradle/maven-metadata.xml
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        //endregion
        //region realm
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.8.0"
        //endregion
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/nickunuchek/maven" }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }

    configurations.all {
        exclude group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', module: 'kotlin-stdlib-jre7'
    }
}

dependencies {
    //REMOVED FROM TOP-LEVEL implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

app/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
   ...

    defaultConfig {
     ...
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }


    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "8g"
        preDexLibraries = false
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }

}

dependencies {
  ...
  implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"//MOVED HERE FROM TOP-LEVEL GRADLE
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: This, surprisingly, worked. Is that an actual Gradle requirement, or just a bug in gms.dependencies?

Answer (score 10):

I resolved the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException by adding the following after applying the google-services plugin at the end of my build script:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

This disables the version check which is buggy in google-services 4.2.0

Comment: It worked. Impressive. How did you find out about that?

Comment: Read the source of the plugin. It's on GitHub somewhere

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem when I'm trying to update to com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0. Deleting the gradle cache also did not help.

The only thing which made the AIOOBE dissapear was completely commenting out the app's maven repo dependencies.

```
  android {
    ...
    dependencies {

      // commented out
      // implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

      // this works
      implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs/dropbox', includes: ['dropbox*.jar', 'json*.jar'])**

    }
  }
```

As you can see in my example, local file dependencies work. However, this is not the solution, maybe only a step in the direction of finding the cause of the error.

After more digging:

It looks like a bug of the google services plugin, and more exactly a bug of the StrictVersionMatcherPlugin which is automatically added with the google play services plugin.

They are checking version of the firebase and play-services libraries and somehow the check runs into an exception. It's a string.indexOf which bugs around.

`if (depFromString.startsWith("project ")) {
          // TODO(paulrashidi): Figure out if a third level dependency shows depFromString.
          // In a project with other project dependencies the dep
          // string will be "project :module1"
          String depName = depFromString.split(":")[1];`

*depName* **is** `project :`, so `split[1]` will fail

Answer (score 0):

the stack-trace hints for the Google Services Gradle plugin:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at com.google.android.gms.dependencies.DependencyInspector
```

and you add the plugin: `classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0"`, but never apply it with: `apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"` (this belongs to the bottom of the file).

having no associated Java dependencies might also cause that; for example:

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0"
```

Comment: `apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"` is added at bottom of `app/build.gradle` file. `implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0"` also is added

Comment: @NickUnuchek as the stack-trace hints for, the dependencies would be the rather interesting part of it, which are redacted out. `disable 'InvalidPackage'` also looks suspicious.

Comment: Added link to myproject at top of question. Please try to sync it in your machine