# Android Studio: Can't sync Gradle Project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am currently experiencing a strange issue with Android Studio and Gradle.

- Android Studio: 3.4.2
- Gradle: 2.10

When I try to sync the Android Studio Project the sync finishes in 969ms with `CONFIGURE SUCCESSFUL` followed by a red `1`

[image: Error "1"]

[Here is Android Studio's IDEA log](https://gist.github.com/idoodler/ee48d9a14a6ada62f80d16aad24278bc)

It looks like there is some kind of exception, but I can't figure out why.

Another interresting thing is that I can execute `./gradlew build --info` without any issues.

Comment: Delete gradle cache folder.

Comment: @SumitShukla I did delete the `.gradle` directory, but without any success.

Answer (score 0):

The logs without the `build.gradle` is useless information ...

and one cannot use Gradle 2.10 with Android Studio 3.4.2

... you'd have to upgrade at least to Gradle 5.1.0.

Comment: But its odd that I was able to successfully build and debug out project on Android Studio 3.4 in the past then.

Comment: @DavidGölzhäuser this likely is coming from Java dependency updates - since another Android Studio version will never cause dependency conflicts. Usually one has to work against it with `exclude` configuration and then add the suitable dependencies  independently. If the question would have featured `dependencies`, I could possibly have left a configuration which builds without the `disableVersionCheck`... this is quite a temporary workaround, unfit for release builds.

Answer (score -1):

I just stumbled over a solution by googling some of the log content.

Adding `com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true`
 after `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`
It just works!

Here is the original post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54504968/1766321

Comment: this is the worst "solution" ever, because it only hides the problem, which cannot be understood while not providing any `build.gradle`, which would show the dependencies - and version conflicts. even if it might appear to work, stability isn't guaranteed at all (and so it might only lead to further issues, down the road). if this makes it build - one can at least be certain, what the actual problem is.